# Improve performance in Microsoft OneDrive for Business webapp

Tags: onedrive, office-365

I used to work with Google Drive and Dropbox but at this new job we have to go through Microsoft's OneDrive for Business.

I use Chrome (latest version) on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, and the web interface is so slow, that I can be wasting more that 15 minutes just to open a file in there.

To make things even worse, there's no OneDrive app for Ubuntu, so I must go through their web interface.

**Question**: what can I do to make things work smoother?